# For which values of $s>0$ the inequality $x^{s+1}\le (y+z)$ holds true with $1\le x\le y+z$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, real-numbers

Let $s\in\mathbb{R}$, $s>0$. Moreover, let
$$1\le x\le y+z.$$

My question is: for which values of $s$ the inequality
$$x^{s+1}\le (y+z)$$
holds true?

I see, e.g., that it holds true for $s=1/2$, $x=y=2, z=1$, but I just can't to find a general relation between $p, s$ in order to make it true in general.

What I can do more than write

$$x\le (y+z)^{1/(s+1)}?$$

Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance?

Comment: There's an obvious simplification in the expression $x^{p(s+1)}\le (y+z)^p$. Try to find it. Showing that you put some thought on the problem will avoid you downvotes.

Comment: @jjagmath thank you. I modified a bit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x=1$ the inequality always holds. For $x>1$ we have
\begin{align}
x^{s+1} \le w & \iff  (s+1)\log x\le \log w\\
&\iff s+1 \le \frac{\log w}{\log x}\\
&\iff s \le \frac{\log w}{\log x}-1
\end{align}